# How do I fix the Problem Error 404 from Webclient

Tags: c#, webclient

#### Hey guys,

I have a problem with my code. Since about a week my code is not working anymore without any changes. I am pretty sure, that my could should work. All I get is Error 404: forbidden.
Below is a snippet of my Code. I also read about adding a header of the webclient, which did not help. Any other suggestions? I am sorry if my syntax is not that good, it is my first post on stackoverflow.

**Thanks in advance!**

```
            string epicId = "ManuelNotManni";
            WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/");
            string result = String.Empty;
            try
            {
                string website = $"{uri.ToString()}{epicId}?";
                result = webClient.DownloadString(website);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Error:\n{ex}");
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            finally
            {
                webClient.Dispose();
            }
```

This is the exact error:

> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden.
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
> at System.Net.WebClient.GetWebResponse(WebRequest request)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadBits(WebRequest request, Stream writeStream)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadDataInternal(Uri address, WebRequest& request)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(Uri address)
> at System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString(String address)
> at TestProject.Program.Main(String[] args) in > C:\Users\Manue\source\repos\TestProject\Program.cs:line 17

Comment: Looks like the API does not allow to call this API without any credentials. That's the you are getting this error. You need to check the API documentation and API support to understand what credentials are required and how to pass them.

Answer (score 0):

You're right. Your code should work fine.
Issue is that URL you're requesting which is actually:

https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/ManuelNotManni?

This returns a 403 status code in any case - no matter if you use a browser, your code or for example [postman](https://www.postman.com/).
I suggest to have a look at the response body while using postman.

It shows this

```html
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
<!--<![endif]-->

<head>

    <title>Attention Required! | Cloudflare</title>

    <meta name="captcha-bypass" id="captcha-bypass" />
```

Comment: Thx for your answer,
thats weird, because when I use Google Chrome with the Url you correctly wrote above, I do get the String I want.
Even with postman I do get something. Not exactly what I want but it doesn't throw an error.

Comment: Ok, I need to revoke my statement. You were right with the postman part. It says:
 Status 403 forbidden
 the request was a legal request but the server is refusing to respond to it. Unlike a  401Unauthorized response, authenticating will make no difference
But the chrome part I wrote was correct, so any other Ideas? :)

Answer (score 0):

Tracker.gg wants API users to register their apps with them before they're given access to the API.

What you need to do is to first head to [their Getting Started page.](https://tracker.gg/developers/docs/getting-started) Here you will have to create an app, which should give you an authentication key.

When you have done this, you want to change your code slightly to add the Authentication Header. Like so for example:

```
        var webClient = new WebClient();
        webclient.Headers.Add("TRN-Api-Key", "XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX")
```

As a sidenote, [WebClient has been deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/networking/6.0/webrequest-deprecated) and it's recommended to use HttpClient from now on. Here's your code with HttpClient instead:

```
var epicId = "ManuelNotManni";
var httpClient = new HttpClient();
httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("TRN-Api-Key", "YOUR API KEY GOES HERE");
// Simplifying Uri creation:
var uri = new Uri($"https://api.tracker.gg/api/v2/rocket-league/standard/profile/epic/{epicId}");
var result = string.Empty; // C# prefers lowercase string
try
{
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Unable to retrieve data for {epicId}.");
        Console.WriteLine($"Statuscode: {response.StatusCode}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Reason: {response.ReasonPhrase}");
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Error:\n{ex}");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
finally
{
    httpClient.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This happens when we violate the Firewall rule set by Cloudflare, you can visit this blog for more details.
https://community.cloudflare.com/t/community-tip-fixing-error-1020-access-denied/66439